# Route for hosts in LAN should not handled by VPN-DNS

Tags: routing, vpn

I use [NordVPN-NetworkManager](https://github.com/Chadsr/NordVPN-NetworkManager) to handle my VPN servers. This works well with NetworkManager, with one single problem: Local hosts will not be resolved by my local DNS (Unify setup) but from the DNS of the VPN.

Is there a way to have multiple DNS servers at the same time for different subnets/"zones", so I can access my local hosts (like my fileserver) and at the same time be connected to the VPN?

Comment: I do it with dnsmasq.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?